# mmap slower than ioremap

Tags: linux, kernel, mmap, gpio

I am developing for an ARM device running Linux 2.6.37. I am trying to toggle an IO pin as fast as possible. I made a little kernel module and a user space application. I tried two things :

1. Manipulate the GPIO control registers directly from the kernel space using `ioremap`.
2. `mmap()` the GPIO control registers without caching and using them from user space.

Both methods work, but the second is about 3 times slower than the first (observed on oscilloscope). I think I disabled all caching mechanisms.

Of course I'd like to get the best of the two worlds : flexibility and ease of development from user space with the speed of kernel space.

Does anybody know why the `mmap()` could be slower than the `ioremap()` ?

Here's my code :

#### Kernel module code

```c
static int ti81xx_usmap_mmap(struct file* pFile, struct vm_area_struct* pVma)
{
  pVma->vm_flags |= VM_RESERVED;
  pVma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(pVma->vm_page_prot);

  if (io_remap_pfn_range(pVma, pVma->vm_start, pVma->vm_pgoff,
                          pVma->vm_end - pVma->vm_start, pVma->vm_page_prot))
     return -EAGAIN;

  pVma->vm_ops = &ti81xx_usmap_vm_ops;
  return 0;
}

static void ti81xx_usmap_test_gpio(void)
{
  u32* pGpIoRegisters = ioremap_nocache(TI81XX_GPIO0_BASE, 0x400);
  const u32 pin = 1 << 24;
  int i;

  /* I should use IO read/write functions instead of pointer deferencing, 
   * but portability isn't the issue here */

  pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_OE >> 2] &= ~pin;    /* Set pin as output*/

  for (i = 0; i < 200000000; ++i)
  {
     pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_SETDATAOUT >> 2] = pin;
     pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT >> 2] = pin;
  }

  pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_OE >> 2] |= pin;    /* Set pin as input*/

  iounmap(pGpIoRegisters);
}
```

#### User space application code

```c
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   int file, i;
   ulong* pGpIoRegisters = NULL;
   ulong pin = 1 << 24;

   file = open("/dev/ti81xx-usmap", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);

   if (file < 0)
   {
      printf("open failed (%d)\n", errno);
      return 1;
   }


   printf("Toggle from kernel space...");
   fflush(stdout);

   ioctl(file, TI81XX_USMAP_IOCTL_TEST_GPIO);

   printf(" done\n");    

   pGpIoRegisters = mmap(NULL, 0x400, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, file, TI81XX_GPIO0_BASE);
   printf("Toggle from user space...");
   fflush(stdout);

   pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_OE >> 2] &= ~pin;

   for (i = 0; i < 30000000; ++i)
   {
      pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_SETDATAOUT >> 2] = pin;
      pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_CLEARDATAOUT >> 2] = pin;
   }

   pGpIoRegisters[OMAP4_GPIO_OE >> 2] |= pin;

   printf(" done\n");
   fflush(stdout);
   munmap(pGpIoRegisters, 0x400);    

   close(file);    
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 3x slower ? Individual oscillation are longer, or overall execution ?

Comment: Both, the oscillations are 3 times slower on the scope, the processor spends more time in the "str" instruction, but I don't know why. Is it waiting for some hardware (bus transfer ?), or some software like a kernel page fault exception handler ? That's the heart of my question...

Comment: Note that in your sample code the number of iterations of the loops is very different.

Comment: @ysap to compensate the fact the one is faster (in frequency) than the other :-). With 30000000 iterations in kernel space, I barely get the time to measure something on my scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because ioremap_nocache() still enables the CPU write buffer in your VM mapping whereas pgprot_noncached() disables both bufferability and cacheability.

Apples to apples comparison would be to use ioremap_strongly_ordered() instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can I have the best of both worlds (write buffer in user space) ? What pgprot should I use ? Do you have any docs about this ?

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that since `mmap` has to check to make sure you're writing to memory you're allowed to write to, it's going to be slower than the kernel version (which I believe/assume doesn't do that kind of checking--with a kernel module you're responsible for testing until you're very sure you're not breaking things).

Try using `do_mmap` (I believe that's the one) to use `mmap` from kernel space, and see how that compares.  If it's comparably faster, then I'm right.  If it's not, it's something else.

Comment: Good idea ! I just tested and it's the same speed as from user space. So it has something to do with mmap, and maybe not with kernel or user space...

Comment: The permission check should be a one-time thing done during mmap(). I don't think the kernel can intercept memory access, once the region is mapped into userspace via TLB, I think any the access is hardware-only.